# How do I generate a map randomly with a specific number of areas?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

How do I generate a map randomly  in a square  with a specific number of areas which is not just a simple regular polygon？

I tried to use noise to generate, but it didn't guarantee the number of areas.

And i tried to use Voronoi tesselation and then merge adjacent regions. But it didn't guarantee the randomness of the map.

In order to make the question clearer, I will give an example.

The picture below has 31 areas.

[image: 31 areas]

In a word,is there exist a method to generate a map randomly similar to the picture above with a specific number of areas which is not just a simple regular polygon？

Comment: I suggest you search for "procedural generation" algorithms for generating maps or areas. Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow, but that search term should help you find resources related to your problem.

Comment: You could generate n random points and use k-means to cluster them into k-areas.  @kaya3's suggestion is probably a more specific fit.

Comment: @AllanWind But this method generates regular polygons.I want to be more random, and the area is not limited to convex polygons.

Comment: @kaya3 I search in Stack Overflow, Google and everywhere i can find.There is no denying the fact that there are many nice  algorithms for generating maps or areas.But they can not guarantee the randomness and the specific number of areas at the same time.

Comment: I found this page fairly quickly: https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/noisy-edges/